# Cut advanced object with plane

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to split an advanced object into 2.
I do have read various articles and question on StackExchange - but I can't simply manage to succeed.

So far I've tried the Bool Tool Difference using a plane and also a box, and also the MACHIN3Tools Mesh Cut.

I've attached a screenshot of the plane I want to use for cutting into the object.

[image]

The goal is to have the top of the bust/statue remove completely, and have the bust/statue "closed" - so I can 3D print if with the slightly modified head missing something :)

If I use a box I get the following result, but I can't easily remove the top part, and the bust/statue also looks "open", which won't work with 3D printing.

[image]

How can I the easiest remove the top of the bust/statue with a plane or a box, alongside having the bust/statue closed (hope it make sense).

Comment: it should work with boolean, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8b7aa030a58c488abe41b4b8b523a42a This contains the plane I would cut after.

Comment: Boolean works fine for me, just rotate your plane 180° or flip its normal: https://zupimages.net/up/22/14/4bdi.jpg

Comment: On your image I can still see the plane - that should also be removed. If I select first plane, then shift select object, and do boolean difference I get the following: https://pasteall.org/blend/a60a4632b1bf45a48c774a3eb3fbe1d4. Not sure if that part is "closed", but I also wanted the other part of the bust/statue.

Comment: This is what I did: https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/14/jdtu.png

Comment: please download this file, you just need to apply the modifier and you're good: https://pasteall.org/blend/5da6e3b60c4b4542b0ad7f1fed290ca3

Comment: Ah, yes - the rotation 180 as you wrote earlier - sorry for missing that. Are the bust/statue closed on the top? Hard for me to see if that is the case.

Comment: yes it is, once you've applied the modifier you can remove the plane and you'll see that it is closed

Comment: Thank you. If you make answer, I can mark it as solved. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Boolean* modifier works fine, just rotate your plane 180° on its own axis or flip its normal, and you'll get that. Then apply the modifier and the shape will be closed.

[image]